# .offset Height property fails for continuous data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="temp" style="width:124px; text-align: justify; display: none;">
</div>
```

I'm performing some action to restrict the contents based on the div's `.offsetHeight` Property. But `.offsetHeight` property fails if data is continuous if there is no space in the data.

Answer (score 0):

.offesetheight property returns the height of the visible area for an object.
Try to use scrollHeight its a cross-browser solution to get the total size of the document.